# Why do System Catalog Object_ids differ for the same object based on the view?

Tags: sql-server

Tables have been created in our SQL Server 2008 R2 database on a local server, and also setup in our SQL Server Express 2008 that installs with Visual Studio 2010 on development machines, using the following script (edited a bit for brievity):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Projects

    (

    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,

    Name NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL

    ) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Projects ADD CONSTRAINT

    PK_Projects PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 

    (

    Id

    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]



GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProjectProperties]

    (

    Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,

    ProjectPath NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL DEFAULT '.',

    )

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ProjectProperties] ADD CONSTRAINT

    FK_ProjectProperties_Projects FOREIGN KEY

    (

    Id

    ) REFERENCES dbo.Projects

    (

    Id

    ) ON UPDATE NO ACTION 

     ON DELETE CASCADE 

GO
```

I query the System Catalog via its views using the following scripts with the associated results (object_ids differ for each copy of the database, but the issues are the same):

```
SELECT object_id, name

FROM sys.indexes AS si

GO
```

```
object_id  name
354100302  PK__ProjectP__3214EC0717036CC0
```

```
SELECT object_id, name

FROM sys.key_constraints AS kc

GO
```

```
object_id  name
402100473  PK__ProjectP__3214EC0717036CC0
```

```
SELECT object_id, name

FROM sys.tables AS st

GO
```

```
object_id  name
354100302  ProjectProperties
```

So my questions are as follows?

1. Why do the object_ids for the Primary Key constraint differ between the sys.indexes and sys.key_constraints views?
2. Why is the object_id for sys.indexes reporting the object_id for the table, if the object_id reported from sys.tables is assumed to be correct?

I'm still fairly new to SQL (~2yrs), so this may be something that's obvious to most SQL gurus, but I just don't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraint and index are not the same thing, so they have different `object_id` values. The index is simply created automatically to implement the constraint. (As a side note, I'd explicitly name the constraint).

The indexes are associated to the table, which is why the `object_id` is the same. If you added additional indexes to the same table then you would see that they also have the same value, but the `index_id` column increments.

The `parent_object_id` in `sys.key_constraints` will also match your table `object_id`. I'm not sure why the people at Microsoft decided to use `object_id` in sys.indexes for the table, but `parent_object_id` in sys.key_constraints, except perhaps that a constraint is considered an object by itself, while an index is not.

Comment: Hi Tom,  Thank you for your answer, as well as additional tips. :)  I also got a bit of additional information in the Technet forums from Tom Cooper that dovetails nicely with the info you provided(http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/transactsql/thread/39c54cf4-29d6-4163-b097-a3060683c5b9).  Basically indexes don't get an object_id, and instead list the table's object_id.

Answer (score 0):

354100302 is the object id of the table,
402100473 is the object id of the constraint

(indexes are keyed off of id, indid)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but since it's possible to create a non-unique index, I think the constraint (uniqueness) and the index (an index) are different things under the covers.  Also, as you point out below, the *object_id* value that appears in sys.indexes is that of the table, not the constraint.

The sys.indexes table, as you have observed, uses the table's *object_id* value for object_id.  The individual indexes are distinguished from each other by the field *index_id*.  While I'm sure there's a reason for this, I don't happen to know what it is, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, it seems from what others have said so far, indexes aren't considered an object under the covers.  Thank you for the help.